# Swift Command Line Tool - replacing regex in a long string is very slow

Tags: swift, regex, string

I'm writing a small command line tool in `Xcode` using `swift`. I have a string that's about 80 lines long and it contains something like this (possibly multiple times):

```
#if true
This should be here
#else
This should not be here
#endif
```

I want to replace all occurrences of this with `This should be here`, or whatever is written between `#if true` and `#else`.
*(I'm doing the same for `#if false`)*

I'm doing it like this:

```
let contents = try String(contentsOf: myFileURL)
contents = contents.replacingOccurrences(of: "#if true\n((.*|\n)*)#else\n(?:(.*|\n)*)#endif", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
```

This technically works, but only if `contents` is **really** small, otherwise it takes way too long (I quit the program after a minute).

Why is this so incredibly slow? Is the regex expression too complicated (regex101.com also can't do it on a large string)? I wouldn't know how to simplify it. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Use [`#if true\n([\s\S]*)#else\n(?:[\s\S]*)#endif`](https://regex101.com/r/RYxzZ3/1) instead

Comment: Thank you! That's way faster. Very interesting :D